# Accelerometer wiring

Tags: arduino, sensor, accelerometer

I try to connect an EVAL-ADXL345Z-M ([Data sheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/609/ADXL345-EP-1503767.pdf)) to an adafruit-feather-m0-adalogger ([Data sheet](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-adalogger/pinouts)).

4 wire SPI is desired.

Is it correct to connect it like:

```
Adafruit Feather M0 to ADXL345;
GND to GND;
MISO to SDO;
MOSI to SDA;
3V to VS;
3V to VIO;
Port 10 (depends on code) to CS
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right to me,

ADXL345 > **Net** < Feather

GND     > **GND** < GND

SCL 14  > **SCK** < 24, Pin 20

SDA 13  > **MOSI** < 23, Pin 19

SDO 12  > **MISO** < 22, Pin 21

CS 7    > **CS**  < *SW Defined*

Vdd I/O 1 > **V+** < 3V

Probably want a decoupling cap on the supply to the ADXL345 as well.